# Node JS passport authentication not using mongoose

Tags: mongodb, authentication, routes, passport.js

I am making a website with node JS that a certain route needs a simple log-in ( even they cannot sign up and I just have the information of the people who can connect to that route in my mongo database).
I had seen some video tutorials and checked the approach however still I have some problem to go further. One of them is that for using passport package do we really need mongoose? because I am using mongodb package in my code as I do not need any schema. I have installed mongodb package in node. I just need to see if user entered correct username and passowrd that already existed in my mongo database and if I got correct password let them route to that location. Obviously if anyone use the route link and did not log in should redirected to log-in page

thanks for advice

Comment: AFAIK there is not even any such dependency for passportjs itself. You seem to be confusing a "plugin" with the core functionality itself. [passport-local](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local) is in fact even a plugin. And all you really do is provide the `LocalStrategy` function with the means to resolve as you see fit

Comment: Thanks but do you mean that even I do not need a session? Is there any simple sample codes that you can refer me to that ? Thanks

Comment: You mean "samples" like in what the link above points to?

Comment: I am a little bit confused by the link. What I see that even no session has been used right?

Comment: Thanks Neil, I think I could handle it however, it is using user.js file rather than mongoDB. But as you said I have some misunderstanding about plug-ins and passport and in general authentication. Is there any good source that you can recommend me to read or watch? thanks